# is there any way to hide browsers loading icon?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Normally if you click a link  the browser displays a little loading icon up in the tab until the page complete loading .

Is there any way to prevent the browser from  displaying this little icon in the tab especially when dealing with iframes loading  ?

Comment: Not if you are using iFrames. Maybe you can load the content via AJAX and display that in a div. But this will only work if the content is on the same origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, but you can design your website as a single page application. Implement your internal links with Javascript handlers which load the content with XMLHttpRequest and replace the current content when the response arrives.

Keep in mind that this makes your content practically invisible to search engines and breaks many browser navigation features your users will be used to.

Answer (score 0):

You could write to the document via JavaScript after it has finished loading by using document.onload

Comment: thank you for your try .. but I want to take a data from the server -using hidden-ifame technique ...